# Memcached security: Allow connections only from certain IP

Tags: php, memcached

So basically all you need to connect to a memcached server is a host name and port. Given that it means anyone can connect to my server and get my informations which is kind of a bad thing. I read that I can implement SASL to require some kind of credentials but I cannot find a *How to install Memcached with SASL for beginners* article, and I was wondering if I could just configure it so that only a certain IP can connect?

I have very little access on the server because I'm on a shared hosting with the cheapest plan.

Comment: if you have very little access, how do you expect to be able to install/configure sasl?

Comment: @MarcB I was hoping there was an alternative to SASL. It seems too complicated for me and even if I manage to get it working I can never be sure with these things I don't understand very well..

Comment: quickest/dirtiest is to just put in a firewall rule to block access to the memcached port from anything but your one IP address, but since you don't have access to the machine at that level, you're probably SOL.

Comment: could you not just have a php script with an if/else that checks the ip? if the ip doesnt match kill page?

Comment: @boomoto Even though PHP can communicate and utilize memcached, memcached does not use PHP

Comment: Are you tried iptables?

Comment: @JevgenijsVaikulis I'm not familiar with this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application run on same server where is memcached you can use socket connections instead of tcp:

```
memcached -s /tmp/memcached.socket -m 256 -u nobody
```

Then you can access to memcached from your app (php version):

```
$memcache = new Memcached;
$memcache->addServer('unix:///tmp/memcached.socket',0);
```

BTW, memcache willl run a bit faster with sockets rather standart tcp connection.

If you have installed memcache on separate server then you can use [iptables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) to filter incoming connections to memcached process. Or any other firewall as well.

Answer (score 0):

Memcached only supports authentication via SASL, and only if it was compiled with SASL support. Which means you will probably not be able to install it yourself on that machine.

But that doesn't even matter: Even if your memached supported SASL, it would still grant an authenticated user access to *all* data. Memcached does not “partition” the data by users. (That's at least how I read [the documentation](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/SASLHowto). Please correct me if anybody finds evidence for the opposite.)

Therefore, what you should be worried about are other users on the same server having access to Memcached. They can read and modify anything you've stored in the local Memcache instance – SASL or not.

By the way, a properly configured Memcached will only listen on local interfaces. Therefore you don't have to worry that it can be accessed from the outside.